# WSO2 - checking access level before calling the web service

Tags: wso2, access-control, xacml, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I know that I can [use WSO2 Entitlement mediator plus XACML](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/08/finegrained-authorization-restful-services-xacml/) to impose such an access control:

- `admin_user` can invoke `UpdateQuote` and `GetQuote`
- `normal_user` can only invoke `GetQuote`

What I need to know is a proper way to find out about access levels **before** invoking the services. Consider that I have designed a user interface and I want to hide or disable the "Update Quote" button for normal user.

Thanks

Comment: maybe you can find out about the user role before invoking the actual service? wouldnt that be enough?

Comment: @user8658912 that is true, but doesn't that require the ui layer to keep track of what role is permitted to call what services? I was thinking of a way to let wso2 do this.

Comment: That's not a feature WSO2 supports. For that you would need to use a Reverse Query - Axiomatics supports that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are trying provide access control for a web application or some user inteface. Basically end user travels through the UI pages, user must be seen only the authorized item. This can be done using Identity Server, There are several options that you have. You can use multiple decision profile in XACML or else you can use XACML search that is provided by Identity Server. Please refer [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/12/06/xacml-based-access-control-for-web-application/) article,  It explains all these possibilities and it has provided samples to implement it using all possible ways. Hope this would be helpful